# How to get huge collection of different jar files?

Tags: java, jar, mvn-repo

for an experiment I'd need a lot of .jar files (about 4000 would be good). I don't really care what kind of .jar files as long as as they are somehow heterogeneous (some small jars, some big ones, ...). Currently I'm clicking myself through mvnrepository which is kind of slow.

Does anybody have an Idea how I can get such an amount of jars autmatically - is there maybe a mass downloader for mvnrepository or some possibility to clone parts of it? I'm also happy with an already existing collectiong of jar files.

Comment: Questions asking for off site resources are off topic here. Plain and simple.

Comment: I'm not explicitly asking for offsite ressources but for possibilities/strategies on how to get a big number of *.jar files :)

Answer (score 2):

As far as question is only related to jar files, I provide below few hints so that you can get more jar files for your experiment.

1. Check eclipse IDE plugins directory. You will get more than 1000 jar files.
2. Next go to .m2 directory. You will get more jar files.
3. If you have Intellij Idea, go to that directory, you will get more than 500 jar files.
4. Download Netbeans IDE, you may get lot of jar files.

For your experiment, you can create Lake of Jar files called JarLake.

Comment: create a spring boot gradle project add other maven libs. and resolve dependencies.

Comment: Haha, when I saw your answer, my first thought was ... "hm, I think i close voted and commented on that question" ... and yea, I did. But a nice answer though ;-)

Comment: Thank you Sir. You are my Guru(Great Teacher in Indian English).

Answer (score 1):

So if you are already `maven` or `gradle` user check your `.m2/repository` directory.

`~/.m2/repository` - for unix/mac
`C:\Users\{your-username}\.m2\repository` - for windows

If you haven't use dependencies management tools yet, just create a project using one and add as many dependencies you want afterward check yours `.m2` directory.